# gcc std::istream 'error: invalid cast from type ‘std::streamsize’ to type ‘std::streamsize’'

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, iostream

Alright, so here is a really weird one. I am reading raw data into a buffer, nothing fancy, my code went like so:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;
/* ... */
static Byte SerializeBuffer[2048];
/* ... */
std::streamsize readInBuffer = 
                data.read((char*)SerializeBuffer, sizeof(SerializeBuffer));
```

But I would keep getting the compile error message `'error: invalid cast from type ‘void *’ to type ‘std::streamsize’'`, No idea why the compiler thought that sizeof was a void pointer. Well I tried casting it in several ways, but the same error kept happening. I ended up with this:

```
std::streamsize dummy = sizeof(SerializeBuffer);
std::streamsize readInBuffer = 
                data.read((char*)SerializeBuffer, reinterpret_cast<std::streamsize>(dummy));
```

Which pops up the following: `error: invalid cast from type ‘std::streamsize’ to type ‘std::streamsize’`

I am at a complete loss. Any other Ideas?

Compiler: gcc 4.4.5
OS: Linux 2.6.35

**edit:**
Same thing on Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `data` is an `istream`, keep in mind that the member `read` returns a reference to `data` (the stream itself), not the number of characters read.

The `void *` stuff is probably because the compiler, to assign it to the `std::streamsize` member, tries to use the implicit conversion to `void *` (the one that is used when you do `if(data) ...`), but still `void *` is not a good match for `std::streamsize`.

By the way, the information about the number of characters read can be obtained, after the call to `read`, using the [`gcount`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/gcount/) method.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/). Read returns a reference to the stream. So what's happening is:

1. You call read, which returns an istream&.
2. You try to assign that istream to a std::streamsize.
3. Since the compiler does not find a suitable way to do this, it tryes to assign the result of the stream's operator void* to your std::streamsize.
4. Since you can't assign these types, an error is produced.

Answer (score 0):

It must be the `std::streamsize readInBuffer = data.read(...` part.  `read` doesn't return size, but the stream itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know how many bytes were read use `readsome()` not `read()`

Comment: AFAIK `readsome` is there to read only the data already in the buffer. In general you should just do `read`+`gcount`.